# heteroscedasticity: weights in lm function in R

Tags: r, regression, lm

I am confused. I have the following model: lm(GAV ~ EMPLOYED). This model has heteroscedasticity, and I believe the error standard deviation of this model can be approximated by a variable called SDL.

I have fitted the corresponding weighted model, resulting after dividing each term by variable SDL, using two forms:

> lm(I(GAV/SDL) ~ I(1/SDL) + I(EMPLOYED/SDL)-1)
>   And
>   lm(GAV ~EMPLOYED,weights = 1/SDL)

I thought they would yield the same results. However, I get different parameters estimates...

Can anyone show me the error I am making?

Thanks in advance!

Fede

Comment: Show up some data so that we can reproduce what you see, e.g. use `dput`.

Answer (score 1):

`help("lm")` clearly explains:

> weighted least squares is used with weights `weights` (that is,
>   minimizing sum(w*e^2));

So:

```
x <- 1:10
set.seed(42)
w <- sample(10)
y <- 1 + 2 * x + rnorm(10, sd = sqrt(w))

lm(y ~ x, weights = 1/w)
#Call:
#  lm(formula = y ~ x, weights = 1/w)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)            x  
#      3.715        1.643  
lm(I(y/w^0.5) ~ I(1/w^0.5) + I(x/w^0.5) - 1)
#Call:
#  lm(formula = I(y/w^0.5) ~ I(1/w^0.5) + I(x/w^0.5) - 1)
#
#Coefficients:
#I(1/w^0.5)  I(x/w^0.5)  
#     3.715       1.643
```

Btw., you might be interested in `library(nlme); help("gls")`. It offers more sophisticated possibilities for modelling heteroscedasticity.

Comment: Thanks so much Roland. I swear I had read the help("lm") before. Silly of me I missed the square root vs. square...
I'll have a look at the package nlme and function gls as you suggest !